# HBase Shell behaviour on giving semicolon

Tags: hbase

I am new to HBase. I was trying basic queries. And like usual SQL way; I was giving semicolon after every query. And query was not running. It just showed next prompt as if it is expecting next part of command.

```
hbase(main):016:0> create 'kau_emp', 'personal data', 'professional data';
hbase(main):017:0* 
hbase(main):018:0* 
hbase(main):019:0*
```

Giving semicolon, \,/ etc. did not help. 
Pressing Ctrl+C exited the shell.

[EDIT]
After searching on internet I found [here](https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/DISTRO-528) that

> The put statement in the hbase shell is ended with a semicolon, which
>   has a special meaning in an interactive ruby shell (which is what the
>   HBase shell is). The semicolon defers execution of the current
>   statement until a statement that doesn't end with a semi-colon is
>   entered. In other words, the put statement isn't being executed until
>   directly before the get statement is executed (so while the ">> no log
>   output" is going on, the put statement has not yet been executed)

So I tried giving semicolon at the end and in next line gave another command without giving semicolon. And it helped.

```
hbase(main):029:0> create 'kau_emp1', 'personal data', 'professional data';
hbase(main):030:0* 
hbase(main):031:0* describe 'kau_emp1'
0 row(s) in 1.2260 seconds
Table kau_emp1 is ENABLED                                                                                                                                          
kau_emp1                                                                                                                                                           
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                                        
{NAME => 'personal data', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', VERSIONS => '1', IN_MEMORY => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}                                              
{NAME => 'professional data', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', VERSIONS => '1', IN_MEMORY => 'false', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE', TTL => 'FOREVER', COMPRESSION => 'NONE', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', BLOCKCACHE => 'true', BLOCKSIZE => '65536', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0'}                                          
2 row(s) in 0.0140 seconds
```

**What is the proper way to come out when you have given semicolon and you do not want to run any other query ?**

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with HBase shell, and by reading your question I got the answer which was about the semicolon and its behavior.

So I will just answer your question: "What is the proper way to come out when you have given semicolon and you do not want to run any other query ?"

Type anything, '1' should work.

```
hbase(main):006:0> count 'pds';
hbase(main):007:0* 1
0 row(s) in 0.2870 seconds

=> 1
```